Area to display MOCs on LEGO Answers
I have been using LEGO Answers for about a week and love it (Pure LEGO Fan). At the moment 
LEGO Answers in BETA and I would like to contribute some ideas to make LEGO Answers a better Website and even make it out of Beta.
Feature Request Idea:

Create an LEGO Presentation Page to show off your Creations, Something like NXT Log.
  You could add your LEGO Creation to the page and show the World your Creation. We could have contests like the best log-House, Robot Arm, or best RC Car. Each Post (Creation) must have an Description, (Optional) Video, (Optional) LDD, and at least 4 Photos. 

I hope you like my Feature Request, (Please spread this post for more Answers).  :)
Why would this Feature Request make LEGO Answers get out of BETA?
The LEGO Presentation Page will improve the post numbers for LEGO Answers.
 

Whilst this might indeed "bring in more users", it's not really what the Stack Exchange sites are designed for:

We welcome questions that are clear and specific, representing real problems that you face; Stack Exchange is not the place for conversation, opinions, or socializing.

In fact it's even in the image you included (emphasis added):

15 questions per day on average is a healthy beta, 5 questions or fewer per day needs some work.

As you mention, there are already a number of sites on the web that are geared up around showcasing your latest MOCs, from dedicated sites such as MOCpages, through to common tags on Flickr.
The best the Stack Exchange engine can really offer you is the ability to update your avatar and possibly include some images in your profile - you don't have to copy this around the network if you'd like to keep it just to LEGO Answers.

Responding to the suggestion that "Photo.SE" does it:
Yep, I'd forgotten that Photo.SE has the weekly featured image image in the header - we could probably do something similar, although I'm not sure how good the small size header image would be at showcasing MOCs.
That said, there's nothing to stop this sort of discussion happening here on Meta.Bricks :)

I think the Stack Exchange engine can handle MOC (Lego Creation). The Photography StackOverflow shows Top Images up top. We could do that with lego.

Photography SE does have a weekly photo contest, but it is running because the site is otherwise active and successful. It's not active and successful because it has a photo sharing contest. This isn't to say Lego SE couldn't grow to that point, but creating a feature that moves away from our Q&A mission and exists largely to boost some numbers isn't going to happen. Those stats aren't the be all and end all of a site. Focusing on quality questions and answers and growing an audience, even if small, tends to pay off a lot better.
